# Will the creation of several million Hard Links on a Windows File System Create performance problems?

Tags: performance, ntfs

I want to implement something similar to Apple TimeMachine on a Windows computer. Windows has a function called [CreateHardLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363860(v=vs.85).aspx). Microsoft's [documentation for hard links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx)  does not imply that using this feature excessively will create performance problems, but Microsoft frequently fails to mention this fact.

Will I get into trouble if I create a zillion hard links on a file system?

Comment: My old rule of thumb was no more than 30,000 files per directory but they may have upped their game... benchmark it and see.

Comment: But I'm not asking per directory, I'm asking per file system...